# Can't edit the cluster created by mlflow model serving

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, mlflow

I'm trying to deploy  Machine learning model into databricks production using mlflow. while in that process, I have registered the model to mlflow models. After that it created the cluster but then it was in pending state forever. when I checked the model events, I see a problem with https proxy, we have global init scripts which contain proxy information.

[image]

Ref: https://docs.databricks.com/applications/mlflow/model-serving.html

so the only way for us to edit the cluster and add them but in that process we are getting an error "error: Cannot edit cluster created by ModelServing".

```
[Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/mlflow/ WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f258247f710>: Failed to establish a new connection:
```

In the "Model Events page", I see the above logs,

Answer (score 0):

The important error here is

```
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

The complaint that pip could not find a version that satisfies the requirement is caused by the failure to connect to the pip repo.

Notice that the installation of the yum packages, e.g. python-pip, succeeded. After a bit of checking, the user discovered that the problem was that he was using a yum proxy, but no proxy was configured for pip. He was able to solve the problem by setting HTTP and HTTPS proxies in his environment:

```
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://x.x.x.x:y

export HTTP_PROXY=http://x.x.x.x:y
```

Comment: how to add them in the cluster ?